# Deny direct access to my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to block direct access to my website.

If the visitor comes from the search engines, can view the site.

If you try to enter the site address directly into the address bar, go to a different page.

How can i do this with htaccess?

Comment: Have you even tried to do some research yourself on this? A quick Google would answer this for you in under 2 minutes. If you _really_ need help, start by showing us what you've tried.

Comment: I had many trials before.

Answer (score 0):

I had many trials before. But there was alot of mistakes. Finally, i tried this code :

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^
RewriteRule ^ https://my_domain.com/error_page/ [NC]

If there is no referer tag, it goes to error page.